# Slow cooking chicken breast

Tags: chicken-breast

How much chicken stock should be used when slow cooking 3 boneless,skinless chicken breast? I used a 8 ounce can of chicken stock,and no water.

Comment: I would suggest that chicken breast is not a great candidate for slow cooking due to is relative leanness and lack of connective tissue.  Perhaps a better approach with your chicken stock is to poach them.

Comment: Assuming you're asking because the slow cooker is your cooking method of choice, here Phyllis, It's probably a good idea to seek out a specific slow cooker recipe to ensure that your measurements are appropriate for the type and quantity of meat being used, for best results. There's an international group on Facebook for slow cooker enthusiasts call Crock Pot Meals that has over 50,000 members who actively share recipes and there are stored recipes of all kinds on their page also.

Comment: More factors that would be helpful to know: what size (volume) is your slow cooker?  What is the total weight of the meat?  Are you planning on using the low or high setting on the slow cooker?  Is the chicken going to be used as whole breasts in a meal or will it be shredded, as for pulled chicken or for taco or enchilada filling?  All of these factors will affect the answer as to whether 8 oz. of canned chicken stock is sufficient for cooking the 3 boneless, skinless chicken breasts.

Answer (score 1):

Typically with slow cookers, you want the liquid to come up at least 1/3 of the way up the meat.

If you're going to be cooking it for a very long time, if your lid doesn't fit well, or for some other reason you suspect there's going to be quite a bit of evaporation, you may want to add more liquid than that.

There are exceptions to this rule, as the shape of the item in there, if it's something that's going to give off lots of moisture, and the amount of food relative to the size of the slow cooker can throw things off, but 1/3 to 1/2 submerged is a good starting point.

Comment: You can cook chicken without stock in a slow cooker, but it's even more important to get proper timings as chicken pieces cooked dry are one of the few things that suffers badly from overcooking in a slow cooker